# "Share the unique values" or "Share unique values" - which one is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

My friend's company is making its slogan. 
My friend suggested "Share the unique values" but I feel like we should drop the word "the" (i.e. "Share unique values" instead)

Am I wrong ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both styles are grammatical, but they mean subtly different things. It comes down to definite vs. indefinite articles.

"Share *the* unique values" implies that there are specific, predefined values that are unique and asked to be shared. Probably, due to lack of other context clues, those of the company the slogan is for (and, even more implicitly, only that company, i.e., the sharing is only one way).

"Share unique values", however, doesn't specify or predefine the unique values to be shared, and thus implies a more egalitarian, two-way sharing.

Bear in mind that the distinction is subtle though, not everyone will notice this (your friend probably hasn't). If your friend insists on keeping the "the", let them. It's perfectly grammatical.